# Как сделать фиктивные переменные из четырех сезонов в питоне?

Tags: python

Как сделать фиктивные переменные из четырех сезонов в питоне? Например, чтобы когда лето она принимала значение 0 и т.д.

```
data=pd.read_csv('FF_monthly_anova_AU.csv', parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True, index_col=[0]) 
data['season']='summer'
data.ix[(data.index.month>=3)&(data.index.month<=5),'season']='autumn'
data.ix[(data.index.month>=6)&(data.index.month<=8),'season']='winter'
data.ix[(data.index.month>=9)&(data.index.month<=11),'season']='spring'
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю стоит посмотреть вот на этот [пример](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) :

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(list('abca'))

pd.get_dummies(s)
       a  b  c
    0  1  0  0
    1  0  1  0
    2  0  0  1
    3  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seasons = ['зима', 'весна', 'лето', 'осень']

def getseason(month_num):
    return seasons[int((month_num + 1)/3)%4]

for item in range(12):
    print(str(item+1) + ': ' + getseason(item))
```

P.S.: Надеюсь суть донёс верно